# How can i login to facebook without showing permission window.?

Tags: facebook

How can I  login to facebook without showing permission window. ?

I never want to show that window in my web.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you're using [OAuth 2.0 in your app to authenticate your users using facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/), then you can't. It's a necessary part of the process.

You can consider reducing the [permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) your app requires to improve your bounce rate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a user to authorise your application then you have to show the authorisations screen as either a page that you redirect to or a pop-up, otherwise it is impossible for Facebook to securely verify the user.

If you want Facebook functionality without having the user grant permissions you are restricted to certain [social plugins](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/) like the share and like buttons, but be aware that if the user is not signed in to Facebook in another tab they will still see a pop-up requesting that they sign in.

Comment: Can you check this issue too? stackoverflow.com/questions/7157440/facebook-registration-issue